# Minimum and Maximum Values Returned by keccak256

Tags: solidity, cryptography, keccak, encryption

In the statement:

```
uint256 x = uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(valuesToEncode)));
```

What’s the minimum and maximum possible values for x?

When I looped random `valuesToEncode` the smallest resulting value for `x` had 73 digits and the largest had 78 digits.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, it's 0 and `2**256-1`, respectively.

Comment: Thanks, but those are the min and max values for uint256, but I don’t think keccak256 will return a value that casts to a uint256 of 0.

Comment: That's why I said in theory. I think no one actually knows what the practical limits are, but if you don't believe in the occurance of hash collision, by enumerating all `2**256-1` integers with some arbitrary prefix or postfix, there should be a value producing 0 or `2**256-1`. Just guessing though.